# Django: DetailView - pk or a slug

Tags: python, django

Old *views.py*

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
...
def foo:
  ...
  return object_detail(request, queryset, id, template_object_name = 'group')
```

New *views.py*

```
class TestDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

def foo:
  ...
  return TestDetailView.as_view(queryset = queryset, context_object_name = 'group')(request)
```

**Error:** eneric detail view TestDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

**Question:** tell me please, how am I supposed to pass *id* in the new *views.py*?

It seems that the raight decision is to overwrite `get_object`, smth like this:

```
def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(TestGroup, id = id)
```

I've also tried this solution:

```
return TestDetailView.as_view(queryset = queryset, context_object_name = 'group')(request, pk = id)
```

But then I've got `Reverse for 'foo.views.testgroup_edit' with arguments '(u'group.id',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Where I call it like this:

```
{% url 'foo.views.testgroup_report_builder' group.id %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use class-based views like this. They are classes. You should get rid of your `foo` function altogether and just reference TestDetailView from the urls.py. If you need to do some extra custom logic in your view which is currently in foo, then subclass TestDetailView and do it there.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. If we move all code to urls.py than what's the point of views.py? It will be just empty for me

Comment: Who said anything about moving all the code to urls.py? You keep the code in views.py, in the TestDetailView class or a subclass of that. You point to that class directly from urls.py.

Comment: Ok, looks like I am starting to understand. That's why it called Class-Based. I call TestDetailView.as_view directly from urls.py, but override get() method, so it handles request in the way I need.

Comment: Yes. Although looking at your code, the method you probably want to override is get_context_data.